# Run vert.x verticle from java class

Tags: vert.x

x verticle which register a handler on an address to listen message sent to the address on event bus and prints it on console . But now i want to unit test it. So can i be simply delpoy verticle in any java method in class which is not vert.x verticle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [PlatformManager](http://vertx.io/api/java/index.html?org/vertx/java/platform/PlatformManager.html): it allows you to deploy verticles programmatically.